# logrotation is gziping log files with incorrect format

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have enabled below logrotation on my VM but somehow logs are being gziped with incorrect format.

**log rotation**

```
/logs/springboot/*.log*
{

    missingok
    minsize 100M
    copytruncate
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    compress
    rotate 5
    postrotate
    endscript
}
```

**Below is how logs are getting gzipped with 0 bytes**

```
-rw------- 1 message message  Aug 12 19:45 message.2021-08-01.6.log.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
-rw------- 1 message message  Aug 12 19:45 message.2021-08-01.7.log.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
-rw------- 1 message message  Aug 12 19:45 message.2021-08-01.8.log.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
-rw------- 1 message message  Aug 12 19:45 message.2021-08-01.9.log.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz
```

Is there a reason why this issue is happening? due to this cron job is failing with below error. I tried running logrotation using debug mode, below is stopper..

```
**compressing log with: /bin/gzip**
removing old log /logs/springboot/message.2021-07-26.0.log.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.6.gz
error: error opening /logs/springboot/message.2021-07-26.0.log.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.1.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz.6.gz: **File name too long**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern, `/logs/springboot/*.log*`, matches not only the logfiles that you want to rotate, but also the rotated logs.

So, it matches both these filenames:

- `message.2021-08-01.6.log`
- `message.2021-08-01.6.log.1.gz`

This means that it will start to rotate already rotated and compressed files, adding `.1.gz` each time.

Make your pattern more restrictive as to avoid matching the rotated log files.  For example, use `/logs/springboot/*.log` to only match the filenames ending in `.log`. Or even better, use `/logs/springboot/message.*.log` since you know your log files have a static filename prefix too.

Comment: Thanks , it worked....  Just one more query if you could answer... Is there a way where we can enable command to delete log files in log rotation? suppose if i want to delete any log older than 1 day using my log rotation script?

Comment: @Surendar You already use `rotate 5`, which means "keep five old rotated logs".  If you have further question, then please open a new question rather than asking followup questions in comments.